# Reducing the running time of R code

Tags: r, performance

I have two tables:
1. A 140,000 X 2 data frame consists of 2 columns and 140,000 rows of text (several words long for each row). See attached file for example:

[Table1](https://ufile.io/tao5g)

2. A similar table but smaller, with only 1 column: 3,500 X 1 data frame consists of 1 column and 3,500 rows of text (one to several words long for each row). See attached file for example:

[Table2](https://ufile.io/b32wl)

I've written a code that runs through each one of the 140,000 rows of "Table1" and searches for the presence of any one of the words in "Table2", and the presence of the word "complex", regardless of upper/lower characters. If the code finds a match - it's written in a new data frame that I've made upfront (let's call it "Table3").

The code is:

```
Table3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(Table1$PDB), ncol = 3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(Table3) <- c("PDB", "Description", "Ligand")

for (i in 1:length(Table1$Description)) {
    for (j in 1:length(Table2$Drug)) {
if (any(tolower(unlist(strsplit(Table1$Description[i], " "))) %in% tolower(Tabe2$Drug[j])) & any(tolower(unlist(strsplit(Table1$Description[i], " "))) %in% "complex")) {
Table3$PDB[i] <- Tabe1$PDB[i]
Table3$Description[i] <- Table1$Description[i]
Table3$Ligand[i] <- Table2$Drug[j] 
  }
print(i)
print(j) 
}
}
```

The code works fine but it's terribly slow. According to my calculations, it would take it around 20 days to run to finish.

Any suggestions on how to make it faster?

Comment: Apparently you want to do a "join" operation. Do some searches with this keyword.

Comment: Please don't share data via file hosting services. Also, most R experts don't appreciate Excel files. We would prefer to see a minimal sample of your data as text in the question, preferable the output of `dput(sample_data.frame)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get some performance gains with `dplyr` and `stringr`.  First, convert `Table2$Drug` to a regex string:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

drug_list <- paste(str_to_lower(Table2$Drug), collapse="|")
```

To show a working example, I'll add the string `"atp-gamma-s"` to `drug_list`, as none of the `Description` values in `EG.csv` contain drug names:

```
drug_list <- paste(c(drug_list, "atp-gamma-s"), collapse="|")
```

Now match `Description` against `drug_list`, and extract matches into `Ligand`.
Also check for `"complex"` with `str_detect`, and then `filter` for positive matches.
(Then remove the `complex_matched` column and you have `Table3`.)

```
Table3 <- Table1 %>% 
  mutate(Ligand = str_extract(str_to_lower(Description), drug_list),
         complex_matched = str_detect(str_to_lower(Description), "complex")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Ligand), 
         complex_matched == TRUE) %>%
  select(-complex_matched)

Table3
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  PDB   Description                                  Ligand   
  <chr> <chr>                                        <chr>    
1 1XP8  Deinococcus radiodurans RecA in complex wit… atp-gamm…
```